# Is there a "Compatibility View Settings" in Windows 10's Edge?

Tags: windows-10, compatibility, microsoft-edge

Before upgrading to Windows 10 from Windows 8.1 I was able to access my payroll and employee resources only by adding the web address to the list in "compatibility view settings" in Internet Explorer. Now that I'm upgraded I'm unable to get to this setting and I'm unable to open the page. I get this message:

> Portal Logo
>
> The Lawson Portal does not support this browser: Netscape.
>   Use the Portal Installation Guide to determine the system requirements needed for running the Lawson Portal.

How can I work around this again?

Comment: IE11 comes with Windows 10 doesn't it? It still has compatibility view settings.

Comment: Wow, didn't realize it was still there. I thought it was replaced with Microsoft edge. Thank you for shedding light on me! Feeling rather sheepish now. Thanks @panhandel

Comment: panhandel, you should make your comment an answer in case Ryan T would like to accept it.

Answer (score 9):

Windows 10 comes with both Edge and IE11.  IE11 still has compatibility view settings where you can apply the same workaround.

Comment: This won't work after June 2022

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having trouble with this, the ellipsis in the top right corner of Edge has an entry titled "Open with Internet Explorer". Alternatively, you can open IE via the Run box (WinKey+R) and typing "iexplore".

Comment: This is option is absent in newer vision of Edge.

Answer (score 2):

So in short, there is no answer for Microsoft Edge. No equivalent setting. Since many things don't work in Edge, my only solution is to go use IE11. That seems like a step backwards but OK.